# Activity not properly managing cursor.

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have an activity that populates a list and does some other things from a cursor. I get the cursor from a method that returns it based on a standard android SQLite query to my database. The method is defined in my `SQLHelper` class. The method opens the database, queries, closed the database, and returns the cursor. After the cursor has been collected in the activity, I call `startManagingCursor(cursor);`

All that works fine.

The problem happens when I launch a sub activity and then come back to the first one. I get a force close with the following output:

```
07-28 18:11:04.674: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {blabla}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: mQuery SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE _id=? 1 
...
07-28 18:11:04.674: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: mQuery SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE _id=? 1 
07-28 18:11:04.674: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.requery(SQLiteQuery.java:162)
07-28 18:11:04.674: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.requery(SQLiteCursor.java:536)

...
07-28 18:11:04.674: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteMisuseException: library routine called out of sequence: handle 0x0
07-28 18:11:04.674: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_bind_string(Native Method)
07-28 18:11:04.674: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:178)
07-28 18:11:04.674: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.requery(SQLiteQuery.java:153)
```

The problem is apparently when it is trying to re-query the cursor. If I close the cursor manually before I launch the intent, then it works fine. But then I need to re-query it manually and isn't that the entire point of `startManagingCursor()`? I have two cursors in the activity that are both created in the same way and I call start managing cursor on both, both cause a crash on resume.

Is there something else I need to do to get my activity to properly manage my cursors?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out that Cursor.requery() is depreciated and I was getting the same error every time I tried to call it. startManagingCursor() was calling requery, as I suppose it should, and that in turn was causing my problems there... I'm not sure why requery is causing an error in this instance, I've used it successfully before.

I ended up rearranging some code, and putting my cursor = SQLHelper.getwhatevercursor() code into onResume() instead of onCreate, as onResume is called right after onCreate anyway. As recommended by Nikola I am also closing the cursors in onPause().

This seems to be working now...

Answer (score 3):

Try closing the cursor in the `onPause()` (`cursor.close()`). If you are using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` you should also detach the cursor from the adapter.

You can requery for the cursor in the `onResume()` method if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, That's probably what I'll end up doing. I just thought that was what startManagingCursor was for... I'm using custom cursor adapters, but I'll see how it goes.